# How do i implement a message box in a Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

I have implemented delete functionality in cocoa application now i want to show one message box when user click on delete button.

Answer (score 41):

Take a look at [`NSAlert`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which has a synchronous [`-runModal`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002032-BCICIIBG) method:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
[alert setMessageText:@"Hi there."];
[alert runModal];
```

As Peter mentions, a better alternative is to use the alert [as a modal sheet](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002032-BCIIJCEE) on the window, e.g.:

```
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window
              modalDelegate:self
             didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                contextInfo:nil];
```

Buttons can be added via [`-addButtonWithTitle:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002032-BCIGGDHD):

```
[a addButtonWithTitle:@"First"];
[a addButtonWithTitle:@"Second"];
```

The return code tells you which button was pressed:

```
- (void) alertDidEnd:(NSAlert *)a returnCode:(NSInteger)rc contextInfo:(void *)ci {
    switch(rc) {
        case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
            // "First" pressed
            break;
        case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
            // "Second" pressed
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better, begin the alert as a sheet on the window that contains the delete button. This way, the user can continue to use any other windows in your application.

Comment: Wow its working fine.But how to put more buttons in this alert and how to get that buttons events

Comment: @mik: By using [`-addButtonWithTitle:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Dialog/Tasks/UsingAlerts.html). There is also a [special on alerts](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Dialog/Tasks/UsingAlerts.html) in the docs that should help you.

Comment: Also may helpful: [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow] completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) { if (returnCode == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn){} }];

Answer (score 11):

Long time has passed since the accepted answer and things have changed:

- Swift is becoming more and more popular.
- `beginSheetModalForWindow(_:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:)` is deprecated, we should use `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` instead.

Latest code sample in Swift:

```
func messageBox() {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = "Do you want to save the changes you made in the document?"
    alert.informativeText = "Your changes will be lost if you don't save them."
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Save")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Don't Save")
    alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(window, completionHandler: savingHandler)
}

func savingHandler(response: NSModalResponse) {
    switch(response) {
    case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
        println("Save")
    case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
        println("Cancel")
    case NSAlertThirdButtonReturn:
        println("Don't Save")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

In case you want a synchronous version:

```
func messageBox() {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = "Do you want to save the changes you made in the document?"
    alert.informativeText = "Your changes will be lost if you don't save them."
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Save")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Don't Save")
    let result = alert.runModal()
    switch(result) {
    case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
        println("Save")
    case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
        println("Cancel")
    case NSAlertThirdButtonReturn:
        println("Don't Save")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```